# How do I send an additional parameter to a function?

Tags: sql, html, web-sql

I have this code which displays text from a Web SQL database:

```
<span contenteditable="true" 
    onkeyup="updateRecord('+item['id']+', this)">' + item['product'] + '</span>
```

When I edit the text it calls the updateRecord function and updates the value.

```
  function updateRecord(id, textEl) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("UPDATE products SET product = ? WHERE id = ?", 
          [textEl.innerHTML, id], null, onError);
    });
  }
```

I have several of these values I'm trying to work with though. So I would like to specify the column. The above code works if I set the column to *product* in the function, in the following code I'm trying to send an additional parameter to the function but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  <span contenteditable="true" 
        onkeyup="updateRecord('+item['id']+', 'product', this)">'+ item['product'] + '</span>

  function updateRecord(id, column, textEl) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("UPDATE products SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?", 
          [column, textEl.innerHTML, id], null, onError);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same with any full-bodied DBMS, you cannot parameterize the column names, only values.
So you need to do it like this

```
  <span contenteditable="true" 
        onkeyup="updateRecord('+item['id']+', 'product', this)">'+ item['product'] + '</span>

  function updateRecord(id, column, textEl) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("UPDATE products SET " + column + " = ? WHERE id = ?", 
          [column, textEl.innerHTML, id], null, onError);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved part of the problem. I didn't include enough info for the syntax error I was also getting to be seen though.